# Is there a way to split a hollow mesh by faces?

Tags: mesh

For example, I have a hollow cubic sphere like this:

[image: a one-piece sphere]

A problem is to split it by all its faces like this:

[image: a sphere with a piece torn off]

The way I have done this one is an application the `P` > `Selection` to an outer face and an appropriate inner one. Then I just have connected appropriate edges to get that little piece. But this way is not really practical since I have to iterate over each face of the sphere manually.

Is there a way to get the result automatically?

Comment: @vklidu, I agree. His answer is good and faster than mine...

Comment: @JachymMichal any reason you ignore us? Seems to be personal now :) I agree with lemon, your answer was faster. I dont have a clue what is going on here, sorry. Split Face by Edge was a new for me and seems to be as less clicks. So why? Thanks for info.

Comment: Hey @vklidu :). Sorry, didn't get any notifications. I deleted the answer because it didn't add very much. Just wanted to keep the site nice and tidy :).

Comment: @JachymMichal Thanks for info :) I was thinking what was wrong with my comment. OK, still seems to me meaningful version. If you change mind (to bing it back), let me know I will delete it.

Comment: Nah, I like your polished version better :). Teamwork, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is JachymMichal's (deleted) a bit polished answer.
With all vertices selected:

- press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> *Split* > **Face by Edges**
- press <kbd>E</kbd> (*Extrude*) <kbd>S</kbd> (*Scale*)
- press <kbd>P</kbd> (*Separate*) by *Loose Parts*

[image]

Scale works for centric objects like a cube or sphere.

Answer (score 6):

You can:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> then *"individual faces"*
- Don't move the extrusion just validate it
- Invert the selection <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to select the base vertices
- <kbd>X</kbd> delete vertices
- <kbd>A</kbd> to select
- <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude
- Again don't move the extrusion just validate it
- <kbd>S</kbd> to scale
- <kbd>P</kbd> to separate by loose parts

[image]

Comment: @JachymMichal, no its ok. But effectively split>Faces by edges (that I did not know) is quicker.

Comment: @JachymMichal why have you deleted your answer? Should work, no?

Comment: Hey :). Sorry, didn't get any notifications. I deleted the answer because it didn't add very much. Just wanted to keep the site nice and tidy :).